# Is possible to loop through sheets and create a string?

Tags: excel, vba

So I was creating a macro that will prepare all data in Temp Files from the options in Dropdown list and then print in PDF.

Im having troubles in the last part, I wanted to create a loop that would loop all sheets and give a String per example of all names of the sheets with Temp on the 4 first letters.

This is the Code I have:

```
Set DV_Cell = Range("C5")

    ExcelPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

'Set range as the List for the dropdown list
    Set rgDV = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S16:S23")

'Loop that changes the value of the C5 then copys the data
    For Each cell In rgDV.Cells
        DV_Cell.Value = cell.Value

        Sheets.Add.Name = "Temp" & DV_Cell.Value
        SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Paste
    Next

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp").ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=ExcelPath & DV_Cell.Value, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

This is the Code I have to Delete the Temp files and it probably similar on what I need to get that string:

```
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    StrS = Sheet.Name
     If Left(StrS, 4) = "Temp" Then
          Sheet.Delete
     End If

Next Sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've created all the Temp sheets, this will order them alphabetically. Then, it will loop through all the sheets in the workbook and select the ones with where the first four letters are "Temp". Once those are all selected it will print all at once to a PDF file.

```
'Order worksheets alphabetically so they print in order
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
For x = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    For y = x To Worksheets.Count
        If UCase(Sheets(y).Name) < UCase(Sheets(x).Name) Then
            Sheets(y).Move before:=Sheets(x)
        End If
    Next
Next

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim replaceSelection As Boolean
replaceSelection = True

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Left(ws.Name, 4) = "Temp" Then
        'This allows for selecting multiple sheets
        ws.Select Replace:=replaceSelection
        replaceSelection = False
    End If
Next ws

'Once all the Temp sheets have been selected you can print all at once to a PDF.
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=excelpath & "\TempSheets.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Hope this is what you're looking for. Good luck with your project!

Comment: But that will create just one string and it will ovewritten by the next Temp Sheet. I needed one that would gather all the sheet names.

Comment: I want to Print to PDF all the sheets that are called Temp.... I will have dinamic quantitys ... sometimes Temp1, Temp2 , other time Temp 1 until Temp34 per example

Comment: I've edited my answer. If this is not correct let me know.

Comment: That works perfectly but creates a PDF per sheet tht is called Temp, my objective would be to create just 1 pdf with all sheets called Temp